# Character is considered by GNAT 18.1 as a string

Tags: string, char, ada

I passed my project from GNAT 7.3.1 to GNAT 18.1 and I have a compilation error on a char affectation.

I want to affect the special character of degree '°' at the end of a string but the compilator returns me this error :

```
R : String := "-NNN.N°";
begin
   ...
   R(R'Last) := '°';
   return R;
end
```

and I got this :

```
strings are delimited by double quote character
expected type "Standard.Character"
found a string type
```

If I replace the symbol ° by a letter or a digit, it works.
If I try to cast into `R(R'Last) := Standard.Character('°');` the compilators says the same thing.

Anyone has already met the same problem ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code (as copied from here and pasted into my editor) is UTF-8 encoded, so your degree sign is encoded using two bytes, hex `C2B0`.

GNAT will expect Latin-1 by default, [so you have to tell it](http://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/building_executable_programs_with_gnat.html#character-set-control) to use UTF-8 in characters/strings/text IO using `-gnatW8`.

Taking the example of `lnlb.adb`,

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Lnlb is
   R : String := "-NNN.NX";
begin
   R(R'Last) := '°';
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (R);
end Lnlb;
```

compile (on macOS)

```
$ gnatmake lnlb.adb -gnatW8
gcc -c -gnatW8 lnlb.adb
gnatbind -x lnlb.ali
gnatlink lnlb.ali
```

and run

```
$ ./lnlb
-NNN.N°
```

Answer (score 4):

Character is defined to be Latin-1, so when using characters not directly available on a standard keyboard, it's best to refer to them some other way than with a Character literal:

```
R (R'Last) := Ada.Characters.Latin_1.Degree_Sign;
```

or

```
R (R'Last) := Character'Val(176); -- Degree symbol
```